# Split a Model's CharField by comma to two variables

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, model, serialization

I have the following Model:

```py
    name = models.CharField(name="location's name",
                            unique=True, max_length=150, blank=False,
                            )
    latitude = models.FloatField(name='Latitude',
                                 unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                 default=1)
    longitude = models.FloatField(name='Longitude',
                                  unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                  default=1)
```

It's serializer:

```py
from .models import LocationInfo
from rest_framework import serializers


class LocationInfoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LocationInfo
        fields = ("location's name", 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'area', 'date_added')
```

I want the latitude and longitude to stay separated variables but when the User inputs them I I want them to be joined.

meaning, something like this I guess:

```py
    name = models.CharField(name="location's name",
                            unique=True, max_length=150, blank=False,
                            )
    lat_lon = models.CharField(name='Latitude/Longitude',
                                 unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                 default=1)
    lat, lon = lat_lon.split(',')
```

```py
# serializers.py

from .models import LocationInfo
from rest_framework import serializers


class LocationInfoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LocationInfo
        fields = ("location's name", 'lat', 'lon', 'area', 'date_added')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve that by splitting before adding to the db (splitting the user input and having two fields, one for latitude and one for longitude), but given your current implementation, you could use a [`@property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods) decorator on your model:

```
class YourModel(yourmodelparents):

    <your_code>

    @property
    def lat(self):
        return self.lat_lon.split(',')[0]

    @property
    def lon(self):
        return self.lat_long.split(',')[1]
```

Then when you have an instance of `YourModel` you can access both `lat` and `lon` fields.

Comment: I don't understand though how it is saved with property?

Comment: it isn't saved. this is a way to leverage a [python class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) - basically whenever you access that attribute you'll be splitting the `lat_lon` field and retrieving the adequate value.

Comment: if you do want to save those fields in your model you need to declare both as CharFields (or FloatFields) and then override either the your [serializer save/create method](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.9.0/rest_framework/serializers.py#L905) or [your model's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).